# Chart.js separate Y and X line

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need separate the Y line (line on the left side) from X line (line on bottom side)

**Libraries:**

- Vue.js 3
- Chart.js 3
- vue-chart-3

**Configuration:**

```
{
  scales: {
    xAxes: {
      offset: true,
      grid: {
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        tickWidth: 1.5,
        tickLength: 5,
        tickColor: '#fff',
        drawOnChartArea: false
      },
      ticks: {},
    },
    yAxes: {
      offset: true,
      grid: {
        borderColor: '#bada55',
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        color: 'rgb(40, 40, 40)',
        tickWidth: 0,
        borderDashOffset: 100
      },
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value: any) {
          if (value < 1000000) {
            let val = (value / 1000)
            return Math.round(val * 100) / 100 + 'k'
          } else {
            let val = (value / 1000000)
            return Math.round(val * 100) / 100 + 'M'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I have a chart:**

[image: chart]

**It should look like this chart: (bottom left corner)**

[image]

Comment: Please include code in your question instead of on an external site, since those links can go dead and will make the question less valuable for readers who come at it later when link might be dead

Comment: Code has been included.